# Check user on LDap with Java

Tags: jakarta-ee, ldap, ldap-query

Can I check a user logged on LDap by his ip address with Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [UnboundID Directory Server](http://www.unboundid.com/products/directory-server.php), a password policy can be created to track the last logon time and last logon IP address. These values are presented as attribute values where the administrator can define the attribute type (name).

Update: There is a new [blog entry](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/last-logon-time-and-ip-address/) with information about getting the last logon IP address and last logon time.